# --Uncaught Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, redux-reducers

1

I am following the Redux tutorials on the Redux site and I am having difficulty using combine reducers. If I run my code without combine reducers, it works fine. As soon as I put the single reducer into the combined reducers function. I get this: Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the store before using combine reducer

```
import {configureStore , combineReducers} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
 import { applyMiddleware } from "redux";
 import thunk from "redux-thunk";
 import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { productReducer } from "./reducers/productReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  products:productReducer
});

 let initialState = {};

 const middleware = [thunk];

const store = configureStore(
   rootReducer,
   initialState,
   composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
 );

 export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a first observation: **you don't need to manually add the `thunk` middleware, call `composeWithDevTools`, or call `applyMiddleware` - the `configureStore` API already does *all* of those for you!**

More specifically in this case:  we normally call the top-level reducer function the "root reducer" to categorize it.

However: `configureStore` expects that you pass that as **a field named `reducer`**, and instead you're passing a field named `rootReducer`.  So, it's correctly pointing out that there is no `reducer` argument being provided.

Change it to `reducer: rootReducer` and it will work.

For that matter, it's `preloadedState`, and not `initialState`.

However, `configureStore` will *also* automatically call `combineReducers` for you, *and* you don't need to provide an empty object.  So this whole thing could really be as short as:

```
import {configureStore , combineReducers} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { productReducer } from "./reducers/productReducer";

const store = configureStore({
   reducer: {
    products: productReducer
   },
});

 export default store;
```

Comment: this is not work

Comment: Sorry, missed the curly braces when writing it. Try it now!